# Bootstrap sort date as a string

Tags: jquery, sorting, twitter-bootstrap, date-sorting

I'm using C# mvc + DataTablesBootstrap and I can't sort by date the table. It is sorting as a string.

I tried to remove the sorting, but it still sort by something

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  /* Init the table */
 var oTable = $('#usertable').dataTable({
               "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
               // "aaSorting": [[5, 'desc']],
                //"oLanguage": { "sZeroRecords": "@Model.NoRecordsMessage" }
            });
        });
```

Do you have any idea how to sort by date by default and after that to be able from the front end to sort by every column of the table?

FYI: I'm new with jquery and bootstrap :)

Comment: I'd remove the C# tag. This has nothing to do with c#

Answer (score 0):

You can sort through your query and just append a hidden column and sort through that column, that will solve the problem :)